# MySqlProfileProvider can't connect to my DB

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm working on a website in ASP.NET and unfortunately I have to use MySql to store the site's data.

I'm really struggling to get MySql work with the `CreateUserWizard` functionality, and I'm just losing it.

Until I defined custom properties in the `Web.Config`, everything was fine, and I actually managed to register some fake users. Then I wanted to add some other properties, like address, gender, and so on. I added those properties in the `Web.Config` like this:

**Web.Config**

```
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySqlProfileProvider" autogenerateschema="True" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" conectionStringName="connMySql" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="Nome" type="string"/>
    <add name="Cognome" type="string"/>
    <add name="Sesso" type="string"/>
    <add name="DataNascita" type="datetime"/>
    <add name="Indirizzo" type="string"/>
    <add name="Citta" type="string"/>
    <add name="Provincia" type="string"/>
    <add name="CAP" type="int"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Please note that my Connection String is correct, since I used it in other parts of my Web.Config and runs just fine.

Later on, in my sign up page, I wrote this code (after validating the input, of course), to update the created user.

**register.aspx.cs**

```
protected void wizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ProfileCommon p = (ProfileCommon)ProfileCommon.Create(wizard1.UserName, true);

    p.Nome = ((TextBox)wizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Nome")).Text;
    p.Cognome = ((TextBox)wizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Cognome")).Text;
    p.Sesso = ((DropDownList)wizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Sesso")).SelectedValue;
    p.DataNascita = System.Convert.ToDateTime(((TextBox)wizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("DataNascita")).Text);
    p.Indirizzo = ((TextBox)wizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Indirizzo")).Text;
    p.Citta = ((TextBox)wizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Citta")).Text;
    p.Provincia = ((TextBox)wizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Provincia")).Text;
    p.CAP = System.Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)wizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("CAP")).Text);

    p.Save();

}
```

All the controls are well positioned into the `.aspx` page.

So, when I run the page, I can see the form and type the data in. Then my code validates the input, and if it's all correct, it creates the user and gets into the `wizard1_CreatedUser` function, where it stops at the `p.Nome = ...` part, which actually is the first instruction that makes use of the `MySqlProfileProvider`.

It just says `Host 'Hostname' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server` **BUT** `MySqlRoleProvider` and `MySqlMembershipProvider` work just fine. In fact, the user is created, but my custom profile data aren't, since the code stops there.

I'm using a DB User with all the privileges.

I'm probably missing something, but I don't really know what.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to enable **Full Trust**.

Also, some files were mispositioned (they were not in the very root of the website).